# debuild notify make[1]: go: Command not found

Tags: go, debian

I need to build a deb for my golang program.

When I run `debuild -uc -us` it tells:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean 
dh clean  
dh_testdir  
dh_auto_clean  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/zbus'  
go clean ./zbus-cli/  
make[1]: go: Command not found  
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 127  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/zbus'  
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 clean returned exit code 2
```

my go compiler is installed correctly, why it still command not found?

Comment: Where did you install go? IIRC, debuild sanitizes the build environment (i.e. resets environment variables such as PATH) before building. If your go is not installed in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, you gonna have a bad time.

Comment: go is located somewhere other than /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin should I soft link go to /usr/local/bin? or are there any command avoid soft link

Comment: Please use the version of Go that is supplied by your distributor, which is usually placed in /usr/bin. Do not attempt to use your own go to build a debian package. Do not pass --prepend-path=... to debuild to coerce it into using your go. This is the only way to ensure that it is possible to build that package on any other system apart from yours.

Comment: Is `golang` or `golang-go` a build dependency of your package?

Comment: thanks, I install go through apt-get and go is found, but my GOPATH is no set in debuild, any way to solve it?

Comment: @enzoyang Use debuild --preserve-env or better RTFM.

Comment: Type man debuild and you get a complete listing of options that would've solved all your problems.

Comment: @FUZxxl: that's not a very good solution really.  The whole point of clearing the environment is to make it more likely that the package build can be repeated.  Ideally the `debian/rules` file should be configuring the environment needed to perform the build.

Comment: @James Henstridge That's what I said in my first comment. "Do not attempt to use your own go to build a debian package". Of course, telling somebody what they try to do is not a particulary smart idea is not very useful so I proceeded to explain how to do what OP wants at the cost of sanity. Maybe I could've worded my second-to-last comment better.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, I just had this problem and found that a package was missing to use this `go` command.

On Ubuntu, I had to install the `golang-go` package.

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

Also, I actually just typed `go` at the terminal and it gave me the same command to type to retrieve that package.